# Place a div as an :after of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The thing I would love to achieve is very simple to explain but I tried everyhting to achieve it.
I would love that ★ to appear right after the 06 using jQuery.

Thanks for any help.

The numbers are created by another function so the `.num` div looks empty in the original html code.

```js
$(".like,.like-yes").insertAfter('.num');
```

```css
.none{display:none}
body{font-family:Arial;font-size:5vw;}
.num{bottom:.5em;position:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=num>01 02 03 04 05 06</div>
<div class=like>★</div><div class="like-yes none">★</div>
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `.appendTo('.num')` ? ( to get the below...)

Comment: the numbers are created buy another function, I forgot to mention, so the .num div is an empty one.

@RokoC.Buljan I tried but it's not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) and turn them into inline boxes

- css update

```js
$(".num").append($('.like,.like-yes'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.like,
.like-yes {
  display: inline;
}

.none {
  display: none
}

.num {
  bottom: .5em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=num>01 02 03 04 05 06</div>
<div class=like>★</div>
<div class="like-yes none">★</div>
```

- or html update

```js
$(".num").append($('.like,.like-yes'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 5vw;
}
.none {
  display: none;
}

.num {
  bottom: .5em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=num>01 02 03 04 05 06</div>
<span class=like>★</span>
<span class="like-yes none">★</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution and no need of javascript. It can be done with pure CSS. You can then style it with jquery (color, visibility...)

```css
.none{display:none}
body{font-family:Arial;font-size:5vw;}
.num{bottom:.5em;position:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;}
.num:after{content:'★'}
```

```html
<div class=num>01 02 03 04 05 06</div>
```

Well, if the start needs to be clickable. Juste adapt code to suits your needed behaviour on click :

```js
 $(".num").append('<a href="#">★</a>');
```

```css
.none{display:none}
body{font-family:Arial;font-size:5vw;}
.num{bottom:.5em;position:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=num>01 02 03 04 05 06</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this cause that star needs to be clickable and start its own function and I can't do that using the :after property.

Comment: Using a class is probably the way to go, jQuery could add an additional class that sets the `content` this way if they should be shown conditionally

Comment: If it must be clickable. Try to use $('num').append(link) with link set with right content and observer.